# Placing Div on top of another DIV

Tags: css

Please see the Image Here http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=56f0053

Currently the code i am using is

```
<div style="background-color:#99CCFF;white-space: nowrap;">
  <hr>
  <p>
    <div style="float: right;">
      <a href="url">Print</a>
    </div>
    <span STYLE="font-size:24; font-weight:bold; color: black">Site:</span>
    Downtown Denver DataCenter - CCODEN44 |
    <span STYLE="font-size:24; font-weight:bold; color: black">Device</span>
    CCODEN44-ACME-RTR-1 |
    <span STYLE="font-size:24; font-weight:bold; color: black">Interface:</span>
    Wilmington DataCenter, DC
    <hr>
  </p>
</div>
```

To make the Image 2 appear as shown in the Figure

Please advice .

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you are asking, but you seem to be asking about chaining divs.  I'll just re-create what I see in the image for you.

```
    <strong>Interface Utilization</strong><br/>
    <div style="background-color:#9CF;white-space:nowrap">
        <span style="float:right"><a href="page">Print</a></span>
        <strong>Site:</strong> Downtown Denver DataCenter - CCODEN44 | <strong>Device:</strong> CCODEN44-ACME-RTR-1 | <strong>Interface:</strong> Wilmington DataCenter, DC
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

first :use `z-order`

second:

```
<div style="position:relative">
<div style="background-color:red;position:absolute;left:0px;right:0px;width:200px;height:200px;">
</div>

<div style="background-color:blue;position:absolute;left:0px;right:0px;width:100px;height:100px;">
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this on top  of your existing div , but i doesn't know how to achive those borders around that div

```
  <div style="background-color:white;white-space: nowrap;">
<p><div style="float: right;"></div><span STYLE="font-size:50; font-weight:bold; color: black">Interface Utilization</span>   </p>
</div>
```